# MySQL: Using the IN clause

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a little problem in using the IN statement. I made an example to demonstrate.

Here is a table called Person where initials is the primary key:

```
 initials      firstName     surname       age
 --------------------------------------------------
     BT          Bill        Thomson       15 
     JS          Jack         Smith        10 
     KM          Katie        Miller       2 
     KW          Keiran      Williams      18 
     LB          Lauren       Bell         6 
     LS           Lucy       Stevens       7
```

So if I have a query like this:
     SELECT * FROM Person WHERE firstName NOT IN ('Bill');
I get all the rows without Bill as expected.

However if I write:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE firstName NOT IN(NULL);
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE firstName IN (NULL);
```

it tells me nothing, just an empty set. Could someone explain to me why? 
Because I have a table where I need to do something like this and it has NULL values which is part of my problem.

Comment: Any comparison to `NULL` -- except for `IS NULL` -- returns either false or NULL (which is treated as false).  This applies to `in` and `not in` as well as other comparison operations.

Comment: I kind of understand what you are saying... but if we take firstName and it has {Bill} and if we compare that to {NULL}, using {Bill} IN {NULL} then I understand why this is false.

I dont understand why {Bill} NOT IN {NULL} is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a bit of intuition rather than rules.

The key aspect of `NULL` is that it does not mean "Oh, I have a value equal to something called NULL".  No, it means:  "I have a value that is unknown".

So, when you say:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE firstName NOT IN (NULL);
```

You are saying:  is `firstName` not in the list of values consisting of an unknown value?  Well, SQL doesn't know.  The value is not known.  It *could* be the same as `firstname`.  It could be `different`.  So, the result is `NULL`.  Note that this will return `NULL` (basically equivalent to false) when other non-matching values are in the list.  It will return false when a matching value is in the list.

When you say:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE firstName IN (NULL);
```

The logic is almost the same. "Is `firstName` in the list of values consisting of an unknown value?"  Well, SQL doesn't know, so the result is `NULL`.  Note that this will return `NULL` (basically equivalent to false) when other non-matching values are in the list.  It will return true when a matching value is in the list, as in:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE firstName IN (firstname, NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the predicates `is not null` or `is null`

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE firstName is not null; 

SELECT * FROM Person WHERE firstName is null;
```

If you have other condtions use the `or` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE firstName is null or firstName in('Bill');
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of the [IN()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator:

> - `expr IN (value,...)`
>
>   ...
>
>   To comply with the SQL standard, `IN` returns `NULL` not only if the expression on the left hand side is `NULL`, but also if no match is found in the list and one of the expressions in the list is `NULL`.
> - `expr NOT IN (value,...)`
>
>   This is the same as NOT (expr IN (value,...))

This means, `expr IN (NULL)` yields `NULL`. In boolean context, this is `FALSE`. This explains why `expr IN (NULL)` does not give you any results.

Additionally, `NOT(NULL)` (as in `NOT(expr IN (NULL))`) also yields `NULL` (and therefore `FALSE` in boolean context). This explains why `expr NOT IN (NULL)` does not give you any results.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is `IS NOT NULL` / `IS NULL` so change as follow

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE firstName IS NOT NULL;
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE firstName IS NULL;
```

You can read [**`Documentation here`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)